# Running java project from command line

Tags: java, command-line, compilation

I'm trying to run my java project from commandline.I have 2 packages looking like that

```
src/catalog1/MainClass - class with main program(he accesses 3 classes below)
src/catalog2/Class1 -
src/catalog2/Class2 -  Three classes that main program uses
src/catalog2/Class3 -
```

How should i compile this project and then run it?I didn't use cmd before i tried to compile mainprogram using javac and and then running by java command but it didn't work,there was an error that it can't find Class1,Class2,Class3.

Comment: Do you have `package` directives at the top of your source files? If so, can you tell us what they are?

Comment: do you mean if my main class imports are proper? in my main program import catalog2.Class1;
import catalog2.Class2;

Comment: See my answer. If `Class1.java` is in a package named *catalog2*, then it must be in a folder named "catalog2" and must also specify `package catalog2;` at the top of the source file. The compiled `Class1.class` would have to be in a "catalog2" folder as well.

Comment: See also http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_packages.htm, which is a short tutorial that covers all the details here.

Answer (score 0):

You should compile all the classes at once as such:

```
javac *.java
```

Comment: file not found *.java

Answer (score 0):

Here's the steps you'd take if you're on a Mac.

Create a Makefile. Save it as `Makefile`.

```
JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6`

all: Class1.java Class2.java Class3.java Class4.java

     ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac *.java

clean: 
   rm *.class
```

Then create a shell script. Save it as `program.sh`

```
JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6`

${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java MainClass
```

Then run `chmod +x program.sh`

In your terminal run:

```
make
./program.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compile your code with `javac` from anywhere, but running it with `java` is a slightly different story.

Class names specified to `java` must be fully qualified (including the package name), and the package structure is tied *directly* to your directory structure.

So in your case, assuming you have `package catalog1;` at the top of `MainClass`, and `package catalog2;` at the top of your source files in "catalog2", then you must run your program from the "src/" directory (or the root directory of wherever your `catalog[12]/*.class` files are) as:

```
java catalog1.MainClass
```

Basically, for a class named `Program` in a package `a.b.c`, all of the following must be true:

- `Program.java` must specify `package a.b.c;`
- `Program.java` must live in `<source>/a/b/c/Program.java`
- `Program.class` must live in `<bin>/a/b/c/Program.class` (it's OK if  and  are the same place).
- `java a.b.c.Program` must be used to run it, and this must be done from the root directory that contains `a/b/c/Program.class` (more accurately, `a.b.c.Program` must be in the class path, but the class path contains an implied "." by default).

I highly recommend [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_packages.htm). It is concise and well-written and goes over the ins and outs of creating, compiling, and using code in packages.

Comment: this runs but without two threads which are objects of Class1 in catalog2 (this class extends runnable)

Comment: @user1840040 That sounds like an entirely different question. Now that you've solved *this* issue and got your code compiled, if you are having issues with the code itself, please [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) after attempting to debug it on your own, and be sure to provide all the relevant details.

Comment: it's compilling but i can't run it, it's working properly in eclipse by the way

Comment: @user1840040 You can't run it because `java` complains that no class is found? Or you can't run it because of some other runtime error caused by your actual code?